# loading even layers of pre-trained BERT for classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I'm using the transformers library of HuggingFace. As far as I know changing the number of hidden layers in the config file leads to loading the first x layers of the pre-trained BERT. I want to load the even layers (or the last x layers) of the pre-trained BERT and then fine-tune them for a classification task.

An example for classification tasks can be found here : [run_glue.py](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/run_glue.py)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you planning to randomly initialize the remaining layers? And does this apply to the encoder *and* decoder part, or only either one?

Comment: I want to prune the rest of the layers. I want to apply this to the encoder layers of BERT